# Empty directory with specific size

Tags: filesystems, directory

How to create an empty directory /tmp/empty that is at least 20MiB in the filesystem. I tried to create a file and delete it, but the size of the directory was not saved. i think that might help i need ext4 filesystem and its fragmentation. I could mount ext4 filesystem in /tmp/empty

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? What do you need such directory for?

Comment: You are worried about the disk fragmentation. Note that the ext4 filesystem divides the disk in block groups. Each directory is associated with a preference for such a block group. Then the /tmp/empy directory will most likely be associated with a part of a disk which has many free blocks close each one to the others.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski is an experiment for classes

Comment: It not clear what you are asking. A directory is a database of files. The size reported in 'ls' is the size of the list - not the size of the content. It is possible to inflate the size of the database on most filesystems (by creating a LOT of files then deleting them) but in order to keep the inflated size you need at least one file in addition to '.' and '..'.

Comment: I guess it's possible to write a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) that will show specific size for an empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with a size of 20 MiB using the dd command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/emptyfile bs=1M count=20
```

Create the ext4 filesystem on the file using the mkfs.ext4 command:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /tmp/emptyfile
```

Mount the filesystem on the /tmp/empty directory:

```
sudo mount -o loop /tmp/emptyfile /tmp/empty
```

Verify the size of the directory using the du command:

```
du -sh /tmp/empty
```

To make this change permanent across reboots, you can add an entry to /etc/fstab:

```
/tmp/emptyfile /tmp/empty ext4 loop 0 0
```

Comment: it doesnt work directory /tmp/empty has dir lost+found

Comment: @jano  Every filesystem needs a `lost+found` in its root directory, or fsck will not function as intended. Specifically, it would have to use blocks in the file system it is already trying to repair, to contain new directory entries for the orphaned blocks, which will destroy more of the file system. So mkfs.ext4 reserves some blocks initially.